# CrawlSpider get source link when crawling

Tags: python, scrapy

Using scrapy's `CrawlSpider`, is there a canonical way to get the url of the page that a **rule follows from**. So for example, if I had a link from *page A* to *page B* when I parse *page B* in the callback method, is there a way to know the url of *page A*? I am interested more in a built-in feature rather than then extending the `CrawlSPider` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your callback you can use the "Referer" header in the response's request headers

```
    def mycallback(self, response):
        print "Referer:", response.request.headers.get("Referer")
        ...
```

It should work with all spiders.